# Can I dump blank instead of null in yaml/pyyaml?

Tags: python, null, yaml, nonetype, pyyaml

Using PyYAML, if I read in a file with blank values in a dict:

```
test_str = '''
attrs:
  first:
  second: value2
'''
```

This returns `None` for the key `first`:

```
>>> data = yaml.load(test_str)
>>> data
{'attrs': {'second': 'value2', 'first': None}}
```

But when writing, the `None` value is replaced with `null`:

```
>>> print(yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
attrs:
  first: null
  second: value2
```

Is there a way to format the dump output to print a blank scalar rather than `null`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need null (None) to be blank lines in dumped yaml?

Comment: We're creating a data entry system for non-technical users so want the interface to be super simple. We decided on blanks rather than null for the input, and it would be great to have the output replicate the input as much as possible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on @Anthon's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37201633/429533), I was able to craft this solution:

```
def represent_none(self, _):
    return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:null', '')

yaml.add_representer(type(None), represent_none)
```

Based on my understanding of the [PyYAML code](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/86a29eb50f26a877d08df317d225cd245fc66859/lib3/yaml/representer.py#L68), adding a representer for an existing type should simply replace the existing representer.

This is a *global* change and that means that all following dumps use a blank. If some unrelated other piece of code in your program relies on `None` to be represented in the "normal" way, e.g. a library that you import and that uses PyYAML as well, that library will no longer work in the exepected way/correctly, in that case subclassing is the correct way to go.

Comment: Wow. Mad skills. This totally works! Thanks Jace, and @Anthon as well

Answer (score 16):

You get `null` because `dump()` uses the `Representer()` which subclasses `SafeRepresenter()` and to represent `None`, the following method is called:

```
def represent_none(self, data):
    return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null',
                                 u'null')
```

As the string `null` is hardcoded, there is no option to `dump()` to change that.

The proper way to solve this in PyYAML is to make your own `Dumper` subclass which has the `Emitter`, `Serializer`, and `Resolver` from the standard `Dumper` that `dump()` uses, but with subclass of `Representer` that represents `None` the way you want it:

```
import sys
import yaml

from yaml.representer import Representer
from yaml.dumper import Dumper
from yaml.emitter import Emitter
from yaml.serializer import Serializer
from yaml.resolver import Resolver


yaml_str = """\
attrs:
  first:
  second: value2
"""

class MyRepresenter(Representer):
    def represent_none(self, data):
        return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null',
                                 u'')

class MyDumper(Emitter, Serializer, MyRepresenter, Resolver):
    def __init__(self, stream,
            default_style=None, default_flow_style=None,
            canonical=None, indent=None, width=None,
            allow_unicode=None, line_break=None,
            encoding=None, explicit_start=None, explicit_end=None,
            version=None, tags=None):
        Emitter.__init__(self, stream, canonical=canonical,
                indent=indent, width=width,
                allow_unicode=allow_unicode, line_break=line_break)
        Serializer.__init__(self, encoding=encoding,
                explicit_start=explicit_start, explicit_end=explicit_end,
                version=version, tags=tags)
        MyRepresenter.__init__(self, default_style=default_style,
                default_flow_style=default_flow_style)
        Resolver.__init__(self)

MyRepresenter.add_representer(type(None),
                              MyRepresenter.represent_none)

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, stream=sys.stdout, Dumper=MyDumper, default_flow_style=False)
```

gives you:

```
attrs:
  first:
  second: value2
```

If that sounds like a lot of overhead just to get rid of `null`, it is. There are some shortcuts you can take and you can even try to graft the alternate function onto the existing `Representer`, but since the actual function taken is referenced in a lookup table ( populated by `add_representer` ) you need to handle at least that reference as well.

The far more easy solution is replace PyYAML with [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) and use its round_trip functionality (disclaimer: I am the author of that package):

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
# trying to round-trip preserve empty scalar
attrs:
  first:
  second: value2
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
assert ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data) == yaml_str
```

apart from emitting `None` as the empty scalar, it also preserves order in mapping keys, comments and tag names, none of which PyYAML does. `ruamel.yaml` also follows the YAML 1.2 specification (from 2009), where PyYAML uses the older YAML 1.1.

---

<sub>The `ruamel.yaml` package can be installed with `pip` from PyPI, or with modern Debian based distributions, also with `apt-get python-ruamel.yaml`</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Extending @Jace Browning's answer while addressing @Anthon's concern, we can use a context manager which remembers the prior implementation of None:

```
class BlankNone(Representer):
    """Print None as blank when used as context manager"""
    def represent_none(self, *_):
        return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', u'')

    def __enter__(self):
        self.prior = Dumper.yaml_representers[type(None)]
        yaml.add_representer(type(None), self.represent_none)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        Dumper.yaml_representers[type(None)] = self.prior
```

which can be used thus:

```
 with BlankNone(), open(file, 'wt') as f:
        yaml.dump(hosts, f)
```

Answer (score -6):

just use string replace

```
print(yaml.dump(data).replace("null", ""))
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is really bad advice: first of all there is no guarantee that the four characters `null` are not part of a larger scalar (e.g. "annulling: 42"), thereby changing data or even crashing loading if those four are part of a tag. Second: you add an extra newline. Third: PyYAML has a stream interface. If you don't specify a stream (as you do), a buffer is made into which is streamed, then the buffer content retrieved. On that you run replace and then stream it out again. That is slow, memory inefficient. If you post-processing do so using something behaves like a stream.