# how can i remove the quotes in around the string and the int in the data dumped in my yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pyyaml

I'm converting csv file to yaml file using python.how can i remove the quotes around the string and int in the yaml file and please also tell a way to remove ... between the lines and please also help with indentation

input in csv file is :-

```
{Field name,type,maxLength,Description}
{name,string,20,sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx}
{DOB,Number,6,the date of birth}
```

my python code is:

```
def csvToYaml(csvFile, output):
stream = open(output, 'w',encoding='utf-8')
csvOpen = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csvFile, 'utf-8'))
keys = next(csvOpen)
hardcoded=['type:object','properties:']
yaml.safe_dump(hardcoded,stream,default_flow_style=False,allow_unicode=True,sort_keys=False)
for row in csvOpen:
    new = 'description:|'
    list_1={row[0]:{
        'type':row[1],
        'MaxLength':row[2],
        }}
    yaml.safe_dump(list_1,stream,default_flow_style=False,sort_keys=False)
    yaml.safe_dump(new,stream,default_flow_style=False,sort_keys=False)
    yaml.safe_dump(row[3],stream,default_flow_style=False,sort_keys=False)
```

i'm expecting the output to be like :

```
type: object
properties:
  name:
    type: string
    MaxLength: 20
    description:|
      name of the person
  DOB:
    type: Number
    MaxLength: 6
    description:|
      the date of birth
```

but i'm getting this output:

```
type: object
properties:
  name:
    type: string
    MaxLength: '20'
description:|
...
sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx
...
  DOB:
    type: Number
    MaxLength: '6'
description:|
...
the date of birth
...
```

Comment: you put `'sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx'` into your line in your input - why are you complaining about it being in the output? Why has your csv { and } and its line start/ends? Why is a dictionary called `list1`? Why dont you just add the description into `list1` as well? `list_1={row[0] : {'type' : row[1], 'MaxLength' : row[2], 'description:|' : row[3] }}`

Comment: how should yaml know that the seperate dump does belong tothe others?

Comment: but then it is dumping: two times like this description:|: sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i'm getting quotes around properties also like this 'properties:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As per basic python by default file opener will consider as string internally. 
   If you will replace `'MaxLength':row[2],` with `'MaxLength':int(row[2]),` then you will get expected output.
2. [Que] How to remove quotes around 'properties:'

**Ans**. 1st parameter of yaml.safedump can accept any datatype. And in your scenario (properties: with colon) internally its considering as dictionary. So you can pass hard-coded value **properties** as dictionary instead of list and value as None.

Check given link for more information [Can I dump blank instead of null in yaml/pyyaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200150/can-i-dump-blank-instead-of-null-in-yaml-pyyaml)

I have not worked on YAML so, I am not sure whether it is optimal solution or not. Please upvote if you find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

This comlpete code (I had to add all the imports and file building etc):

**With [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):**

```
import yaml
import csv 

with open ("k.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write("""{Field name,type,maxLength,Description}
{name,string,20,sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx}
{DOB,Number,6,the date of birth}""") 

def csvToYaml(csvFile, output):
    stream = open(output, 'w',encoding='utf-8')
    csvOpen = csv.reader(csvFile)
    keys = next(csvOpen)
    hardcoded=['type:object','properties:']
    yaml.safe_dump(hardcoded,stream,default_flow_style=False,allow_unicode=True,sort_keys=False)
    for row in csvOpen: 
        list_1={row[0]:{
            'type':row[1],
            'MaxLength':row[2],
            'description:|':row[3]
            }}
        yaml.safe_dump(list_1,stream,default_flow_style=False,sort_keys=False)


with open("k.txt") as f:
    csvToYaml(f,"out.txt")

with open("out.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

prints:

```
- type:object
- 'properties:'
'{name':
  type: string
  MaxLength: '20'
  description:|: sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx}
'{DOB':
  type: Number
  MaxLength: '6'
  description:|: the date of birth}
```

You need to remove your "extraneous" dumping calls to `yaml.safe_dump(new, ...)`. It has superflous characters in it, you might need to switch to some other yaml package or find the parameters that allow you to minimize the generated yaml.

---

**With [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basicuse.html):**

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import csv 

with open ("k.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write("""Field name,type,maxLength,Description
name,string,20,sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx
DOB,Number,6,the date of birth""") 

yaml = YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=6, offset=3)

def csvToYaml(csvFile, output):
    stream = open(output, 'w',encoding='utf-8')
    csvOpen = csv.reader(csvFile)
    keys = next(csvOpen)
    hardcoded=['type:object','properties:']
    yaml.dump(hardcoded,stream)
    for row in csvOpen: 
        list_1= { row[0]: {
            'type':row[1],
            'MaxLength':row[2],
            'description:|':row[3]
            }}
        yaml.dump(list_1,stream)


with open("k.txt") as f:
    csvToYaml(f,"out.txt")

with open("out.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
   -  type:object
   -  'properties:'
name:
    type: string
    MaxLength: '20'
    description:|: sdscbjxfgc xtcvhgx
DOB:
    type: Number
    MaxLength: '6'
    description:|: the date of birth
```

Comment: thanks for the code but how will i remove the quotes around properties:

Comment: i removed the quotes around intger maxLength by typecasting row[2] but can't find a way to remove quotes around string properties.

Answer (score 0):

Only JSON solved similar issue for me, sorry YAML.