# How to replace the NoneType representer in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I am working with YAML files that are processed by an application for calculations.  This application only supports `~` for the `None` assignment, but `ruamel.yaml` uses both `''` and the `null` keyword.

For example:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml_example = """\
info:
  value1: null
  value2: [5, null, 12]
"""

yaml = YAML()
info = yaml.load(yaml_example)
with open('textfile.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(info, file)
```

This would yield

```
info:
  value1:
  value2: [5, null, 12]
```

However, I need the output to be something like this:

```
info:
  value1: ~
  value2: [5, ~, 12]
```

How can I get the output with `~`?

I've looked at the following question, but I haven't been able to apply it to `ruamel.yaml` successfully.
[Can I dump blank instead of null in yaml/pyyaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200150/can-i-dump-blank-instead-of-null-in-yaml-pyyaml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to change the representer for the null tag:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_example = """\
info:
  value1: null
  value2: [5, null, 12]
"""

def _represent_none(self, data):
    if len(self.represented_objects) == 0 and not self.serializer.use_explicit_start:
        return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:null', 'null')
    return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:null', "~")

ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(type(None), _represent_none)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
info = yaml.load(yaml_example)
yaml.dump(info, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
info:
  value1: ~
  value2: [5, ~, 12]
```

Comment: Wow, that works great, thank you! For future reference, this will be a global change for this program correct? I do not think there are any other dependencies that this change would affect if it is, but I want to make sure my notes are thorough.

Comment: Yes that is a global change, if you don't want that you'll need to make a subclass of RoundTripRepresenter and add all the other `.add_representers` copy-pasted from `representer.py`